# import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat not suggested by IntelliJ

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, assertj

Newbie, big project, copy/paste unit testing task.
Using IntelliJ Ultimate, when trying to import assertThat(), I get to choose only between:

```
import static com.mysema.commons.lang.Assert.assertThat;
```

or

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

But what i need as an option =>

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
```

Co-workers have no problem with imports on the same project on their machines.
No error, when i just copy/paste import from another class. But IntelliJ doesn't suggest imports I need!
Any ideas?

Tried to:

1. invalidate caches
2. restore default settings
3. reload all gradle projects
4. delete .gradle and .idea folders
5. clean/build project directory
6. restart pc...
   No result

Comment: Is Assertj in your project configuration? What happens if you just copy and paste the import you want? Does it error, or show up as unused?

Comment: Yes, AssertJ library is on our project. If I copy/paste no error occur. Copied import works fine.

Comment: Try to re-import the project from scratch. `File | Close Project` -> Close the IDE. Open OS file explorer and delete all .iml files and the .idea directory. Re-import the project as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_import_project_start. If the problem remains, contact JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Check if the problem is reproduced in the latest build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. Nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

1. File -> Project Structure -> Global Libraries
2. Add - New Global Library from Maven -> assertj.core.
3. Choose version. Apply.

Comment: Thank you! But this did not help as well.